# Can't access to public member

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with accessing to my database. I won't paste the whole code, just an actual part:

filmdb.h

```
class Film: public QWidget
{
...
public:
    QSqlDatabase db;
}
```

addfilm.h

```
#include "filmdb.h"

class AddFilm: public QWidget
{
...
}
```

filmdb.cpp

```
Film::Film(QWidget *pwgt): QWidget (pwgt)
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("films.fdtb");
    ...
}
```

addfilm.cpp

```
#include "addfilm.h" // so filmdb.h is included

AddFilm::AddFilm(QWidget *pwgt): QWidget(pwgt)
{
    //here is the problem
    //when i try to use db
    //compilator says undeclared identifier
}
```

So why i cant use db in addfilm.cpp? Thanks.

Comment: How are `AddFilm` and `Film` related to each other? (this is a hint, not a question)

Comment: Because `db` is not a member of `AddFilm`.

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the error and the error message itself

Comment: Did you intend to make `AddFilm` inherit from `Film`? As it stands, it inherits from `QWidget`...

Comment: db is a public member and i include filmdb.h (where it is declared) to addfilm.h Is it wrong?

Comment: `db` is a public member of `Film`, not of `AddFilm`. It looks like you are trying to access it as if it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db` is a member of class `Film` but you are trying to use in class `AddFilm` which doesn't derive from `Film`...

If you mean that `AddFilm` is a specialization of `Film` then you have to derive `AddFilm` from `Film`, doing in `addfilm.h` something like:

```
#include "filmdb.h"

class AddFilm: public Film
{
...
}
```

at this point you can just use `db` in `AddFilm::AddFilm()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do this, then create instance of Film class and you be able to use db.

In addFilm constructor:

```
Film *mFilm = new Film;
mFilm->db//do actions with db
```

Comment: @NicholasM main idea is to create instance and after that try to call something. it can be pointer or not, it is just example. Author should decide himself what he want use and what he need.

Comment: @NicholasM moreover, it is a qwidget subclass. If author want show it, widget appear and disappear(because ordinary member will be deleted as you know)